# Is this a proof that ALL generalized inverses of a hermitian matrix is also hermitian?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, solution-verification, inverse

I know that the inverse of a nonsingular hermitian matrix is also hermitian (symmetric if matrix is real). I also know that a singular hermitian matrix has **a** hermitian generalized inverse.

But are **ALL** generalized inverses of a hermitian matrix also hermitian? I could not find an answer anywhere, and the following proof suggests so. Please help me find any mistakes if it is not so.

---

**Definition 1**: A matrix $A^- \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times m}$ is a generalized inverse of a matrix $A \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n}$ if $A A^- A = A$.

**Lemma 2**: Every hermitian matrix $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ can be decomposed into a product of a matrix and its conjugate transpose: $A = X^\dagger X$, where $X \in \mathbb{C}^{r \times n}$ ([proof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50380061/decompose-hermitian-matrix-into-product-of-vector-and-its-conjugate-transpose)).

Now, I will take this $X$ and construct a perpendicular (orthogonal) projection matrix onto its column space $C(X)$.

**Definition 2**: $M \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ is a perpendicular projection matrix onto $X$ if and only if:

1. $v \in C(X) \Rightarrow Mv = v$
2. $w \perp C(X) \Rightarrow Mw = 0$

**Lemma 3**: $M$ is a perpendicular projection matrix onto $C(M) = C(X)$ if and only if:

1. $MM = M$
2. $M^\dagger = M$

The proof for lemma 3 is taken from [Plane Answers to Complex Questions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387947671) Proposition B.32 and Theorem B.33 and slightly modified to account for complex matrices.

**Lemma 4**: Perpendicular projection matrices are unique (Proposition B.34 from [Plane Answers to Complex Questions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387947671)).

**Lemma 5**: If $G$ is a generalized inverse for $X^\dagger X$, then $X G X^\dagger X = X$ (Proposition B.43 from [Plane Answers to Complex Questions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387947671)).

**Lemma 6**: The (unique) perpendicular projection matrix onto $C(X)$ is $X (X^\dagger X)^- X^\dagger$.

> Proof: Show that this matrix holds properties in definition 2:
>
> 1. For $v \in C(X)$, $v = Xb$ for some $b \in \mathbb{C}^n$. So, using lemma 5:
>    $$X (X^\dagger X)^- X^\dagger v = X (X^\dagger X)^- X^\dagger Xb = Xb = v$$
> 2. For $w \perp C(X)$, $X^\dagger w = 0$. So:
>    $$X (X^\dagger X)^- X^\dagger w = 0$$
>
> Since lemma 4 says that perpendicular projection operators are unique, this is the one and only perpendicular projection operator onto $C(X)$.

Since lemma 3 tells us that a perpendicular projection matrix is hermitian, the matrix from lemma 6 must be hermitian:

$$X (X^\dagger X)^- X^\dagger = (X (X^\dagger X)^- X^\dagger )^\dagger = X ((X^\dagger X)^-)^\dagger X^\dagger $$

Since $X^\dagger X = A$, we have:

$$A^- = (A^-)^\dagger $$

This works for any arbitrary hermitian matrix $A$. Does this prove that any generalized inverse of a non-zero hermitian matrix is hermitian?

Comment: Every square matrix is a generalised inverse of the zero matrix, but certainly there are some square matrices that aren’t symmetric/Hermitian (unless $n=1$).

Comment: @user1551 that is a nice observation. I will require that rank(A) > 0 while I try to find where this requirement arises in my proof.

Comment: That won’t make any difference. One can still adjoin the zero matrix via a direct sum to a nonzero or nonsingular Hermitian matrix to reach the same conclusion. E.g. every matrix of the form $\pmatrix{1\\ &B_{2\times2}}$ is a generalised inverse to $A=\pmatrix{1\\ &0\\ &&0}$, but $B$ can be chosen to be non-Hermitian.

Comment: @user1551 It seems that I need to examine my last statement more carefully, which is that $A B A^\dagger = A B^\dagger A^\dagger \Rightarrow B = B^\dagger $, and restrict the condition of $A$ or $X$ such that this statement holds.